# Activeadmin, page_action and cancan rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

How to manage access to custom_page actions? I have this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Import' do
  menu false

  content do
    panel t('views.import.title') do
      render 'form'
    end
  end

  page_action :parse, method: :post do
    @import = current_user.imports.new(params[:import])
    if @import.save
      @import.process
    end
  end

  page_action :check_status do
    imports = current_user.imports.finished.unreaded
    size = imports.size
    imports.update_all readed: true
    render json: {has_new_ended: size}
  end
end
```

Now, access to this action has only admin, cuz the his rules looks like

```
can :manage, :all
```

But I need access this actions to other roles. If I do this for some role, it's not helps.

```
can [:check_status, :parse], ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'Import'
```

And this

```
can [:manage, :parse, :check_status], Import
```

Answer (score 1):

By using following code in `ability.rb`, you should be able to get all the permissions for the current user when he is in the custom page.

```
can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: "Dashboard", namespace_name: "admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to authorize the actions. 
See more: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#2-check-abilities--authorization

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your action name and page name.

```
can :parse, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'Import'
can :check_status, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'Import'
```